# I am trying to divide this code in the separate files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i tried this codes in the codeigniter.
This code is running when this all together , But when i separate these, i create a css file and also a js file then give them a link to load the css and js file then this code is not running, how can separate its js and css?

To load my css in the codeigniter i write this code

```
<?= link_tag('style.css'); ?>
```

To load my js file in the codeigniter i write this code

```
 <script type="" src="<?= base_url(''); ?>">


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg" src="<?php echo base_url('assests/img/profile.png');?>" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang = "en">

   <head> 
      <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
      <title>CodeIgniter View Example</title> 
      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" 
         href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css"> 
      <script type = 'text/javascript' src = "<?php echo base_url(); 
         ?>js/sample.js"></script> 
   </head>

   <body> 
      <a href = 'javascript:test()'>Click Here</a> to execute the javascript function. 
   </body>

</html>
```

see tut [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_adding_js_css.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your DOM dependent code within some `function` and call that `function` on `onload` of your document body as follows:

JS Code which need to put in your separate .js file:

```
function myJSFunction(){
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Modify HTML `<body>` tag as follows:

```
<body onload="myJSFunction()">
   <h2>Image Modal</h2>
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url('path/style.css'); ?> "> 
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "<?php echo base_url('path/sample.js'); 
         ?>"></script>
```